The feasibility of using wind turbines to construct a giant quadcopter
I'm not looking for a definitive yes/no answer here so much as an illustration of the calculation with some fairly reasonable assumptions and references to relevant and useful data.
My assumptions are:

It's possible to modify the generator in the wind turbine so that it can be operated as a motor,
The motor efficiency would be the same as the generator's efficiency,
Power into the motor would be the same as the turbine's rated output power,
The wind turbine can operate while its shaft is oriented upwards, in the zenith-pointing direction, and
Power will be supplied from the ground via a high-voltage line.

I imagine this enormous quadcopter being used only during fair weather as an amusement ride or attraction, similar to a tethered helium balloon. There might be other applications in, for example, construction.

I'm specifically interested in understanding whether a modern wind turbine and its blades are already engineered to be light enough and powerful enough for a limited-use VTOL aircraft.

The lithium ion battery fire would be epic.


Motors and generators are essentially the same thing, there may be some modifications required, but it would not substantially change size, weight, power, etc.
The motoring efficiency would be very similar to the generating efficiency.
The motoring power would be very similar to the generating power.
Unknown consequences of changing the orientation.  Wind turbines have a thrust bearing, but it is incorrectly oriented (push vs. pull).  The blade & hub is not designed for the loads in that direction, it would be interesting to see how the overall loads changed.
Power from the ground, OK.

Problems:

Quadcopters rely on rapid changes in RPM to modulate thrust for control.  Wind turbines are enormous and have enormous inertia.  Rapidly changing RPM would require a far larger motor than a turbine's generator.  There is generally considered to be an upper limit on how big a rotor can be and still use RPM control -- while we can discuss the exact value of that limit, it is much smaller than a modern wind turbine.
Wind turbines have variable pitch blades.  You might conceive of using blade pitch instead of RPM to control the vehicle.  However, wind turbines are designed to change blade pitch very slowly, it would require a major re-design of the pitch control mechanism to achieve the fast rate control required to fly an aircraft.  That mechanism would be larger and heavier.
Wind turbine blades are designed to extract power from the air with great efficiency -- i.e. to be driven.  They are not designed to efficiently produce thrust.  A windmilling rotor operates in a fundamentally different flow regime than a thrusting rotor.  Although they look similar, the design of a windmill rotor is fundamentally different from a propeller.  Consequently, propellers make terrible windmills and windmills make terrible propellers.


That last point is really interesting. Do you remember from where you learned that?

@phil1008 https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8851/31936

@phil1008 When we talk about an an actuator disk, we describe the flow in different states.  Typically we call them propeller, windmill, turbulent wake, vortex ring, and propeller brake - though some authors use different terms depending on whether they come from the propeller, helicopter, or wind turbine community.  The differences are determined by things like whether thrust is positive or negative, power is positive or negative, and flow acceleration is positive or negative.  In some of these situations (e.g. vortex ring state), simple momentum theory does not work.
